# Deploying static site that uses a node rest api on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a static site that i want to deploy on Heroku and this site also uses one node rest service. My question is should i deploy both apps independently, or there is another way??

Comment: "static site that uses a node rest api"—then it's not a static site, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your backend has stuff like database, security and business logic, so its common to take this responsibility separated, its more easy to do maintenance and implement new features, in other hands the front-end has the logic to show data and interact with user, so is possible to do many front-ends to a one back-end, but if you does not separate then that is not possible to make it in simple way. So separate the concerns and deploy to Heroku two applications.

Comment: Ok, thanks. can i deploy two apps if i am using the free plan?

Comment: **Yes, you can!**